# Wordpress - Change the "Log in to reply" URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the URL for the "Log in to reply link" in my comments as shown in this image v

[image]

I did come across this snippet of code that i thought would help, but it just seems to make the link disappear altogether.

```html
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in' ) ) {

 add_filter( 'comment_reply_link', 't5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in' ); /** * Replaces the log-in link with an empty string. * * @param string $link * @return string */
 function t5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in( $link ) { 
     if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['user_ID'] ) && get_option( 'comment_registration' ) ) { 
         return ''; // add your link here 
        } 
        return $link; 

     } 

 }
```

I realise that I am probably missing something really really obvious as I am completely new to php, so please be gentle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you found was to remove the link to reply entirely. You just want to filter the function in order to add custom wording. You can learn more about Wordpress filters [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

```
function change_comment_reply_text( $link ) {
    $link = str_replace( 'Log in to Reply', 'Change to This Text', $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'comment_reply_link', 'change_comment_reply_text' );
```

to change the URL you can change the wordpress login URL with the filter below

```
add_filter('login_url','custom_login_url');

function custom_login_url($login_url) {

  return home_url('/my-account/'); //change my-account to whatever the url slug is for the page you created
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand, I don't actually want to change the text of the link, I'm trying to change the URL of the link. It currently takes me to the wordpress admin login page, but i want it to take the user to a page i have created.

Comment: Is the page you created a login page?

Comment: Yes, it is a page displaying a WooCommerce login form, this is where i want my users to log in

Comment: I have added a new filter to my answer which changes the login URL for the site so that the log in to reply link or any other wordpress generated login links will go to your woocommerce login form page.